# JS find all previous items of target item

Tags: javascript

How do I find all the previous items from the array by target item via javascript?

Suppose I have an array of items `["Volvo", "BMW", "Mercedez", "Suzuki", "Honda"]` and if my target value is `Suzuki` I should get `["Volvo", "BMW", "Mercedez"]`

Thank you!

Comment: You can combine [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) with [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), give it a try!

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+js+get+all+array+items+before+a+specific+value) of [How can I return all previous items in a JavaScript array than a current value?](/q/17436573/4642212).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array#findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to find the index of the item you're looking for in the array, and then use [Array#slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get the result you're looking for.

```js
const array = ["Volvo", "BMW", "Mercedez", "Suzuki", "Honda"];

const index = array.findIndex(v => v === 'Suzuki');

const result = array.slice(0, index);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: What if I also want to include the target item? Should I be doing ```array.slice(0, index+1)``` ?

Comment: Yes, you can just add 1

Comment: Thanks man! Need to wait a few minutes to accept it as a correct answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the array methods [**array.slice()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [**array.indexOf()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```js
const data = ["Volvo", "BMW", "Mercedez", "Suzuki", "Honda"];

const result = data.slice(0, data.indexOf("Suzuki"));

console.log(result);
```